# How to map Json object to pojo, if JSON has duplicate keys in object

Tags: java, json, javabeans, pojo, jsonschema2pojo

Below is the example of JSON object.

```
{  
   "primaryAccountNumber":"4353453",
   "processingCode":"3453",
   "transactionAmount":"34534",
   "transmissionDateTime":"34534",
   "receiptsFields":{  
      "line":"BHN VALIDATION - DAR",
      "line":"Phone",
      "line":":Amount: 25.00",
      "line":"BHN Order ID: 9GMAQH0",
      "line":"ALL SALES FINAL",
      "line":"Terms and Conditions",
      "line":"Store ID: 06220",
      "line":"redemptionAccountNumber",
      "line":"",
      "line":"",
      "line":"",
      "line":"",
      "line":"",
      "line":"",
      "line":"",
      "line":"",
      "line":":"
   },
   "termsAndConditions":"Terms and Conditions of the card will be displayed in this area. The maximum characters allowed are nine hundred and ninety nine (999)."
}
```

What will be the type of receiptsFields to map in POJO ? For example transmissionDateTime we have String. Same suggest me type for receiptsFields so that response will map into pojo automatically.

Comment: It will be object... you can also use below link to convert json to pojo
http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: using Object its not working

Answer (score -1):

The name of your type does not matter, as long as it has the right properties in it. In your case something like

```
public class ReceiptField{
    public String line;
}
```

However, I don't think this JSON does what you want to achieve.
In your *receiptsFields* property, all properties are named *line*, so only the last one will be taken into account (being ":" in your example). An array seems a better fit here.

EDIT : To answer your comment, do you have control on the input JSON ? 
If so it would be :

```
 {
  "primaryAccountNumber": "4353453",
  "processingCode": "3453",
  "transactionAmount": "34534",
  "transmissionDateTime": "34534",
  "receiptsFields": [
    "BHN VALIDATION - DAR",
    "Phone",
    ":Amount: 25.00",
    "BHN Order ID: 9GMAQH0",
    "ALL SALES FINAL",
    "Terms and Conditions",
    "Store ID: 06220",
    "redemptionAccountNumber",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    ":"
  ],
  "termsAndConditions": "Terms and Conditions of the card will be displayed in this area. The maximum characters allowed are nine hundred and ninety nine (999)."
}
```

Comment: you are right. For Now I am getting ":" only. Can you please give me example for Array ? like how we can handle

Comment: See my edit, it supposes to change the JSON input though.

Comment: No I dont have Control over Input Json. Input JSON will be same like that. We cant change input String.

Comment: Then if you need all information in receiptFields, I'm afraid you have no other choice than parsing it manually, because as @Jaboy mentionned, non unique property names aren't suppose to occur. My advice is to do string manipulation to transform input JSON into what I suggested, then parse it into an object.